# "unlist" a list stored in a variable

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a dataframe with a two odd variables.  For one one variable, each cell stores a list whose contents is simply a vector of two numbers.  For the other variable, each cell stores a three dimensional array (even though only two dimensions are necessary) of 8 numbers.

I want to simplify the dataset by breaking out the odd variable into separate variables.  I figured out how to break all the data out using a for loop but this is very slow. I know apply is supposed to be generally quicker, but I can't figure out how I would translate this to apply.  Is it possible, or is there a better way to do this?

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (length(df$coordinates.coordinates[[i]]>0)){
    df[i,"coordinates.lon"]<- df$coordinates.coordinates[[i]][1]
    df[i,"coordinates.lat"]<- df$coordinates.coordinates[[i]][2]
  }
  if (length(df$place.bounding_box.coordinates[[i]]>0)){
    df[i,"place.bounding_box.a.lon"] <-df$place.bounding_box.coordinates[[i]][1,1,1]
    df[i,"place.bounding_box.b.lon"] <-df$place.bounding_box.coordinates[[i]][1,2,1]
    df[i,"place.bounding_box.c.lon"] <-df$place.bounding_box.coordinates[[i]][1,3,1]
    df[i,"place.bounding_box.d.lon"] <-df$place.bounding_box.coordinates[[i]][1,4,1]
    df[i,"place.bounding_box.a.lat"] <-df$place.bounding_box.coordinates[[i]][1,1,2]
    df[i,"place.bounding_box.b.lat"] <-df$place.bounding_box.coordinates[[i]][1,2,2]
    df[i,"place.bounding_box.c.lat"] <-df$place.bounding_box.coordinates[[i]][1,3,2]
        df[i,"place.bounding_box.d.lat"] <-df$place.bounding_box.coordinates[[i]][1,4,2]
      }
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is an example dataframe with one case (via dput)

```
structure(list(coordinates.coordinates = list(c(112.088477, -7.227974
)), place.bounding_box.coordinates = list(structure(c(112.044456, 
112.044456, 112.143242, 112.143242, -7.263067, -7.134563, -7.134563, 
-7.263067), .Dim = c(1L, 4L, 2L)))), .Names = c("coordinates.coordinates", 
"place.bounding_box.coordinates"), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

In case it helps, this is the data format that gets out when you try to read Twitter stream data using jsonlite's stream_in function (with flatten=TRUE)

Comment: Could you provide example data?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df = data_frame(
  coordinates.coordinates = 
    list(c(0, 1), c(2, 3)),
  place.bounding_box.coordinates =
    list(array(0, dim=c(1, 4, 2)),
         array(1, dim=c(1, 4, 2))))

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  do(with(., data_frame(
    longitude = coordinates.coordinates[1],
    latitude = coordinates.coordinates[2]) %>% bind_cols(
      place.bounding_box.coordinates %>%
        as.data.frame %>%
        setNames(c(
          "place.bounding_box.a.lon",
          "place.bounding_box.b.lon",
          "place.bounding_box.c.lon",
          "place.bounding_box.d.lon",
          "place.bounding_box.a.lat",
          "place.bounding_box.b.lat",
          "place.bounding_box.c.lat",
          "place.bounding_box.d.lat")))))
```